# Weird re-render behavior with react material-ui dialog

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-hooks, rendering

## Background

So I build a front-end project for a delivery service, based on React and Material UI.
I was asked to use a Dialog window that will be opened when clicking on item, and there the user will have the opportunity to customize the item.
The dialog can be seen here(very simple: item photo, name, desc, and customization options):

https://ibb.co/GFkpy8Q

(Sorry for the pixelization)

## The problem

I use react hooks in this project, and that why manage the Dialog's state.
Although simple, I stumbled upon few problems with how elements got re-rendered/not re-rendered(when expected):

1. The `"checked"` prop of the checkboxes uses `Array.some`, to see if the unique ID of the checkbox is in the state Array. The checkboxes are not being set to checked when clicking on them. The `onChange` prop simply pushes the checkbox's value to the state array and sets the state:

```
const [array, setArray] = React.useState([]);
...
<Checkbox
  checked={
    array.some(
      item => item._id === subOption._id
    )
  }
  onChange={() => setArray(array.push(subOption))}
/>
```

**The `onChange` action works properly**, so why the `"checked"` prop doesn't work properly?

2. When a checkbox is checked, I want to add a small quantity field next to it, so the user will be able to choose the quantity of the `subOption` he shall receive.
   So I use the next well-practiced pattern:

```
{array.some(item => item._id === subOption._id) &&
  (
    <QuantityField />
  )
}
```

**The problem is that the QuantityField is not shown after the checkbox get checked.**

3. If I exit the Dialog and enter it again, I suddenly see the checked checkbox is checked, and the QuantityField is shown next to it
4. If I change the item's quantity with the general QuantityField you can see at the bottom left of the Dialog image, suddenly all the checked checkboxes gets unchecked 
   The general QuantityField uses a state of it's own, and is not connected to any of the checkboxes.

From what I could see after I tried to debug the weird behavior, I can say that the render action of the Dialog component isn't working as expected. The states are updated, but doesn't trigger a re-render of the Dialog tree. Actually, it is wrong to say that, as the Dialog tree gets re-rendered, but the "checked" prop is not being re-checked during the re-render; but a complete un-mount and re-mount of the Dialog shakes the tree right.

Hope for an interesting answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would change how you are using `setArray`. See from [`Array.prototype.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) documentation:

> The `push()` method adds one or more elements to the end of an array and returns the new length of the array.

Also using `.push()` on the state is not allowed because **never should mutate the state directly**.

Suggested solution instead:

```
onChange={() => setArray(prevState => [...prevState, subOption])}
```